# Why are three large partitions created when installing Fedora with the encrypted disk option?

Tags: fedora, partition, luks, partition-table

I've just installed Fedora 37 on a 2TB SSD, and see this partition table:

[image: Two wasted partitions after installing Fedora]

I understand the role of the [EFI partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition), but why is it so large? 0.6 gigs seems excessive.

What is the role of the second partition? How is that 1GiB used?

Answer (score 2):

> I understand the role of the EFI partition, but why is it so large? 0.6 gigs seems excessive.

600 MiB might be bigger than necessary, but the default must be a "one size fits all" solution and there are use cases that can require more space like multibooting with a single EFI partition or [firmware updates](https://github.com/rhinstaller/anaconda/pull/1644). See also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/722435/does-debian-11-5-really-need-500mb-partition-for-efi).

> What is the role of the second partition? How is that 1GiB used?

That's your `/boot`. Fedora currently requires separate `/boot` partition for with LUKS (or LVM). Your kernel and [initrd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk) are stored there.